# How do you make a video disappear after it finishes playing so the user could continue using the app?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I wrote some code to play a video after launch, but after the video is played, it isnt going back to the storyboard, it is just stuck in this loop where it goes back to the main board for a second then goes black (probably the end of the video)

In the debug console it says "2019-05-05 01:32:33.766132+0800 app[35989:1028569] [AVKit] Target view should be our own view when the full screen view controller is being transitioned!"

I have tried things like having something that senses the end of a video but those are not helping.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        playVideo()
    }

    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

    private func playVideo() {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType:"m4v") else {
            debugPrint("video.m4v not found")
            return
        }
        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        playerController.player = player
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerController.player?.currentItem)
        playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false

        present(playerController, animated: true) {
            player.play()
        }
    }

    @objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
        playerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I expected the video to go away after it finished playing so the user could see the home screen of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    playVideo()
}
```

the playerVC is dismissed , after that the vc appears and `viewDidAppear` is called so it'll show the player again , consider a once bool

```
var once = true
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if once {
      playVideo()
      once = false
    }
}
```

or show it with DispatchAfter in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: You don't need a `once` property. Use `if isBeingPresented || isMovingToParent {`

Comment: @rmaddy which of those would ever be true?

Comment: @matt It depends on how the view controller was originally displayed.

Comment: @rmaddy Suppose it’s the root view controller. Then both are false and we will never run.  Or even worse, suppose it’s not, and can be pushed or presented again later. Then we will still run more than once.

Comment: actually i don't trust on these properties and many more like `parent` they sometimes doesn't work as expected

Comment: @matt I foget to mention that. To also handle the root controller, you need `if isBeingPresented || isMovingToParent || view.window == nil {`. That check should work for any view controller, no matter how it was originally shown.

Comment: @rmaddy The answer as given works and says exactly what it means.

Comment: @matt Yes, I know it works. I'm simply pointing out that it isn't necessary to add and check your own property since `UIViewController` already provides the needed checks. Though it might be helpful to add a simple `UIViewController` extension that wraps this `if` statement I mentioned into `var isFirstDisplay: Bool` or something similar.

Comment: @rmaddy I can't believe we're having this silly conversation, but I assure you that in `viewDidAppear` if ViewController is the root view controller, the test `if isBeingPresented || isMovingToParent || view.window == nil` will fail at launch. Please try it yourself and see.

Comment: @matt OK, the check for the first view of the root controller using `view.window == nil` works in `viewWillAppear` but not `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: @matt @ rmaddy thank you guys!! it solved my issue, I was stressing out so much last night.